# How do I convert a ISO 8601 timestamp to a Unix timestamp using Shell?

Tags: timestamp

I am trying to convert a ISO 8601 timestamp to a Unix timestamp using Shell.

MediaWiki sadly only supports ISO 8601 timestamps, but I need one in Unix. So is there an easy way I can convert this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `date` util on Unix-systems, you can do e.g.

```
$ date -d "2017-02-18T23:54:57+01:00" "+%s"
1285716915
```

The result is the Unix timestamp.